# wants to get data from two tables conditional based

Tags: mysql

i wants to populate a dropdown based on two tables data....one is vms_vendor_job_submission and other is vms_offer, multiple resumes are submitted for a job, now clients wants to create an offer for some candidates, if he creates and offer then the data will be submitted to the vms_offer table with the foreign key of vms_vendor_job_submission table,

so now what i want is that while populating data in the dropdown of submissions....i don't wants to show those submissions which have record in submission table or with status 1(pending) or 3 (approved).

```
"select s.* from vms_vendor_job_submission s LEFT JOIN vms_offer o ON s.id=o.submission_id AND (o.status = '2' ) where s.job_id="101" and s.resume_status='7'";
```

Actually what i want is pick all records s table against the conditions and then check those in the o table if there is any match then check the status of that match if its status is 2 then show that record otherwise hide that.....and if there is no match in second table then display it.....u got my point right?

Comment: so, what is the issue/error you see?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with your current query ?

Comment: its returning extra records....not comparing from the second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.* 
  FROM vms_vendor_job_submission s
  LEFT 
  JOIN vms_offer o
    ON s.id = o.submission_id
 WHERE s.job_id = 101 
   AND IF(s.id = o.submission_id, o.status = 2 AND s.resume_status = 7,s.resume_status = 7);
```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: I'm not familiar with IF.,. AND syntax